Apache Ignite Get Operation takes Time time
We have a Spring Boot application in which ignite has been used as  Embedded [server node]
Application has caches configured various purpose as below

MasterData in Cache – Data is fetched from File and loaded to Cache
during Spring Startup
Audit Cache – This is configured with Database [Oracle] to write
entries to Database via Ignite as Write Behind

WE are facing quite delay in Get and Put operation in Cache [ around 200ms ] but varies
during Load Testing [
1 user – less than 1 ms
50 user – sometimes it goes 200ms
590, 33, 152, 136, 17
Current Setup

Apache 2.14 | Jdk 8 | Spring Boot Containerized as Docker
JDK 8 Alpine image used
No Native Persistence Used
No Custom Data Region Configuration
Default Settings of  Heap used [ Current Core 8 Core 32 GB] used ON Heap =20% of Total Memory]
No On Heap Flag is configured ,Enabled IGNITE_QUITE=false too
MasterData – no Expiry Policy has been
Set already JVM G1GC settings
No Errors are visible in Console of the application
Caches are ATOMIC, REPLICATED [ As of now single Node of application only started and tested]
Ignite xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

 
 
 
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                            <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
                    
                        </bean>
                    
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    <!-- 47100 communication -->
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="AppCluster" />
        <property name="systemThreadPoolSize" value="8" />
        <property name="stripedPoolSize" value="8" />
        <property name="clientMode" value="false" />
        <property name="workDirectory"  value="/ignite/workdir/" />
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean
                class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean
                        class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                                <value>cust-services:47500..47520</value>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="includeEventTypes">
                        <list>
                            <util:constant
                                static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_EXPIRED" />

                        </list>
        </property>
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <!-- Configuration for MasterDataCache -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="MasterDataCache"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                    <property name="queryEntities">
                        <list>
                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                                <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                <property name="valueType" value="java.util.HashMap"/>
                                <property name="keyFieldName" value="dataId"/>
                                <property name="keyFields">
                                    <list>
                                        <value>dataId</value>
                                    </list>
                                </property>
                                <property name="fields">
                                    <map>
                                        <entry key="dataId" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                    </map>
                                </property>
                                <property name="aliases">
                                    <map>
                                        <entry key="dataId" value="dataId"/>                                                                          
                                    </map>
                                </property>
                            </bean>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>


Loading Code on Startup
package com.custom;



import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CodeStartup {
  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CodeStartup.class);
  
  
  public static Ignite ignite = null;
  
  static String igniteconfigpath = System.getProperty("ignite.config.location");
  
  protected Ignite ignite() throws Exception {
    try {
      logger.debug("reading ignite config from :" + igniteconfigpath);
      igniteconfigpath = igniteconfigpath.replace("file:", "");
      File file = new File(igniteconfigpath);
      String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
     
      InputStream in = IOUtils.toInputStream(str, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
      ignite = Ignition.start(in);
      if (ignite == null)
        logger.warn("**** Ignite Creation Failed****"); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new Exception("Failed to initialize ignite!! Caused :" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    } 
    return ignite;
  }
}

//Above class is called class shown Below
package com.customer;


 

import com.custom.CodeStartup;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import javax.cache.CacheException;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class CustomCodeStartup extends CodeStartup {
  private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomCodeStartup.class);
  private static final String _KEY="someFixedKey";
 
  
  public Ignite getIgnite() {
    try {
      ignite();
      logger.info("Ignite data grid initialised");
      logger.info("loading custom cache");
      loadCache(ignite);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new RuntimeException("Application Startup Failed ,caused " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } 
    return ignite;
  }
  
  private void loadCache(Ignite ignite) throws StartUpException, ConfigurationException {
    logger.info(">>> Loading cache: ");
    loadMasterDataCache(ignite);
  
  }
   
  
  private void loadMasterDataCache(Ignite ignite) throws StartUpException {
    try {
      logger.info(">>> Loading cache: MasterDataCache cache - started");
      IgniteCache<String, HashMap<String, String>> cache = ignite.cache("MasterDataCache");
      if (cache != null) {
      
      //Reading configuration File 
           Map<String, String> config = readFromPropertyFile();
           cache.put(_KEY, config);
          } 
           
        } 
        logger.info(">>> Loaded MasterDataCache cache successfully");
      } else {
        logger.info(">>> Loading cache: MasterDataCache  null");
      } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new StartUpException("Error loading MasterDataCache chache", e);
    } 
  }
  
  
}



public class b {
  static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(b.class);
  
  public static Ignite ig = Ignition.ignite("AppCluster"));
     private static final String _KEY="someFixedKey";
     
   public static HashMap getConfig( ) {

       IgniteCache<String, HashMap<String,String>> masterDataCache = ig.cache("MasterDataCache");
     return (HashMap)masterDataCache.get(_KEY);

   }
}


What is correct approach to Instantiate  1. Ignite & 2. IgniteCache Object in Spring
Can we declare Ignite and IgniteCache as Static
and use get or put operations in Utility Methods?
Note: Assume you are going to do in Spring Boot , with ignite as embedded server node

public class SomeClass{
    public static Ignite ig;
    static {
        ig = Ignition.ignite(IConfigurations.getConfigValue("SomeCluster"));
            }
    IgniteCache<String, MasterData> cache;

    public MasterData getData(String id) {
        cache = ig.cache("MasterDataCache");
        MasterData data= cache.get(id);
        return (MasterData ) data;
   }

Following were found in thread dump in Runnable state
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IncompleteCacheObject. (IncompleteCacheObject.java:44) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.toCacheObject(CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.java:1433) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.CacheDataRowAdapter.readIncompleteValue(CacheDataRowAdapter.java:680) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.CacheDataRowAdapter.readFragment(CacheDataRowAdapter.java:500) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.CacheDataRowAdapter.readIncomplete(CacheDataRowAdapter.java:411) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.CacheDataRowAdapter.doInitFromLink(CacheDataRowAdapter.java:316) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.CacheDataRowAdapter.initFromLink(CacheDataRowAdapter.java:165) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.CacheDataRowAdapter.initFromLink(CacheDataRowAdapter.java:136) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.InlineIndexTree.createIndexRow(InlineIndexTree.java:360) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.io.AbstractInlineLeafIO.getLookupRow(AbstractInlineLeafIO.java:129) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.io.AbstractInlineLeafIO.getLookupRow(AbstractInlineLeafIO.java:37) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.InlineIndexTree.getRow(InlineIndexTree.java:403) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.InlineIndexTree.getRow(InlineIndexTree.java:72) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.getRow(BPlusTree.java:5693) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.InlineIndexTree.compare(InlineIndexTree.java:309) 
at org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.InlineIndexTree.comp

